# When i push firebase notification, receive method working twice on iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My App.xaml.cs

I send only one notification but method working twice on ios (the method working one times on android)

```
CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += (s, p) =>
            {
               // go twice inside of this method on IOS
            };
```

Comment: So The Test Phone showing notification two times But i want onky one times. help please!

Comment: Consider raising the issue on github : https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissuem . Or  use `Azure Notification Hubs` instead , docs here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started

Comment: Where do you subscribe to the event (where is CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += part). It should be inside protected override void OnStart